# Liferay Velocity Template, loop through array

Tags: liferay, velocity

I have created a custom Web Content Structure, which takes an array as it's only input (called "theArray"). Something like:

```
[
  ["vs303","The first Title","2","4","5","7"],
  ["vs606","The second Title","4","5","7","8"],
  ["vs808","The third Title","3","2","11","7"]
]
```

When I try to loop through the array in the Velocity Template, it is not showing anything:

```
#set ($foo = ${theArray.getData()})

#foreach ($bars in $foo)

  #foreach ($bar in $bars)
    <p>$bar</p>
  #end

#end
```

Where have I gone wrong? Do I need to declare the var to be an array?

*note
If put the array in the template, the loop works. If I get the array from the liferay webcontent structure via the `getData` method, nothing is output.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array like this (you don't need to use `getData` method):

```
#set($foo = [
  ["vs303","The first Title","2","4","5","7"],
  ["vs606","The second Title","4","5","7","8"],
  ["vs808","The third Title","3","2","11","7"]
])

#foreach ($bars in $foo)
    #foreach ($bar in $bars)
        <p>$bar</p>
    #end
#end
```

Comment: thanks for looking at this, however, I need to use the `getData` method, so that i can reuse the template with different data sets. the above code works if i set the array within the template, but if I get the array from the webcontent structure using `getData`, it does not work.

Comment: So the problem is that you don't have an array, but only string. I don't know there is available tool to "deserialize" this string to array. Maybe you can create your own according to [this](https://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/custom-velocity-tools-and-liferay-6-0)

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your problem is that 1.> when you set the array in template its working because the original array data type is preserved. 2> When you are using your getData() function you are probably getting a string which velocity iterator is not able to understand thats why not working.

I am not sure about the implementation of getData() method, but you can try doing:

1> If possible make the return type of getData() a Array.

2> If this is not possible. You can create a static method to convert theArray.getData() Type to Array Type. Set this method to velocity context and use this static method in template.

```
             #set ($foo = ${STATIC_METHOD(theArray.getData())} )
```